# MVC jquery grid is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to use a plug in for jquery grid (gijgo.com) in my mvc application.
I have carefully completed all the steps mentioned on [c-sharpcorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3ff6df/jquery-grid-with-Asp-Net-mvc/) and/or [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/895928/How-to-use-jQuery-Grid-with-ASP-NET-MVC) but when I run the application, I got javascript runtime error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 40, column 9 in http://localhost:36552/Default1/Index

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'grid'
```

Here is my view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/grid-0.5.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqgrid;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jqgrid = $("#grid1").grid({
            dataKey: "ID",
            uiLibrary: "bootstrap",
            columns: [
                { field: "ID", width: 50, sortable: true },
                { field: "Name", sortable: true },
                { field: "PlaceOfBirth", title: "Place Of Birth", sortable: true },
                { field: "DateOfBirth", title: "Date Of Birth", sortable: true }
            ],
            pager: { enable: true, limit: 5, sizes: [2, 5, 10, 20] }
        });


    });
</script>
<table id="grid1"></table>
```

when I click on the ".grid" and press F12, it goes to the corresponding function in grid.0.5.2.js.

Has anybody found a solution for this problem?

Comment: don't you need to add a `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: Yes, also tried adding bootstrap.js, but same result...

Comment: One additionalinformation, when I write the same html code in notepad and add .js files in the same folder then i works fine, but not in VS2013,,,am i missing something?

Comment: wrong path to js files?

Comment: not possible...i am doing drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `Url.Content` method in order to be sure that the path is build correctly.
Example:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid-0.5.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```